# To conclude with theorem without proof .

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

I have seen many, and highly cited technical papers, which has some analysis ( e.g. stability or convergence analysis), and after the analysis, the author concludes with a statement like (We conclude this section with the following theorem:) without formal proof after the theorem. As if the proof follows from the previous analysis. Is this acceptable?

Comment: What is sfot???

Comment: for (soft-question). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the proof really is in the previous analysis, or can easily be constructed from it, then yes.